# Multi tenancy laravel app hosted on elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudflare, multi-tenant

Question is related to the sub domain that I pointed to the EB environment domain from CloudFlare. The issue is how can I identify the tenant based on sub domain?

In my localhost environment I created a Virtual host by editing the host file like this 127.0.0.1 netlink after creating the virtual host I can ping to that api endpoints like this netlink:8000/api

How can I achieve the same with domain like this netlink.mydomain.com ? In here netlink is the sub domain created for the tenant in CloudFlare host ( CNAME record ). netlink.mydomain.com this domain being pointed to the Elastic Beanstalk domain.

Do I need to create VH in AWS ?

Note: I'm using the laravel tenancy package to create tenants. https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3